# Metrizable topology given by convergence of sequences

Tags: general-topology, metrizability

Let $\alpha$ be a (Hausdorff) topology on a set $X$. Let $T_{\alpha} = \{ \beta \text{ topology on } X \mid \forall (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ in } X, x \in X: x_n \overset{\alpha} {\longrightarrow} x \Longleftrightarrow x_n \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} x \}$ be the set of all topologies  $\beta$ on $X$ that agree on sequences with $\alpha$.

The question is: Does there exist any metrizable topology in $T_{\alpha}$? If so, is it unique?

Comment: If it exists, it is certainly unique. In a metrizable space, the convergent sequences with their limits give you the closed sets and hence the topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For topologies $\alpha, \beta$ on $X$ define:

1. $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, if for all sequences
   $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $x \in X$ it holds:
   $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \overset{\alpha} {\longrightarrow} x \Longrightarrow (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} x $
2. $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$, if
   $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ and $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$

Obviously, $\rightarrow$ is reflexive and transitive on the set of all topologies on $X$, hence $\leftrightarrow$ is an equivalence relation and
$T_\alpha$ as defined above is the equivalence class of $\alpha$.

Recall that a topological space is *sequential*, if for each non-closed set $A$ there exists a sequence in $A$, which converges to an element outside of $A$.
Obviously, each first countable space is sequential.

The following is easy to see:

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be topologies on $X$.

1. $\beta \subset \alpha  \Rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \beta$
2. If $\alpha$ is sequential, then
   $\beta \subset \alpha  \Leftrightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \beta$
3. If $\alpha, \beta$ are sequential, then
   $\beta = \alpha  \Leftrightarrow \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$

Hence: 
If $\alpha$ is sequential and $T_\alpha$ as defined above contains a metrizable topology, then $\alpha$ is metrizable.

This provides a lot of topologies $\alpha$, such that
$T_\alpha$ contains no metrizable topology.